# QT background process for keyboard input sniffing

Tags: qt, background

am working on a simple application which would run in the background and capture keyboard input from the user (like a keylogger , but for the LAN )

I am sending UDP packets for transferring keystrokes 
But the problem of capturing keyboard input from a background process still seems unreachable .
So help needed .

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it for Windows you will have to use the WinAPI : `SetWindowsHookEx`. I don't know for Linux or MacOS

**Edit :**

Here is the documentation : [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Wih an exemple [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#installing_releasing).

Comment: Thanks , i know for linux , was wondering about windows itself  , can you give me some link or detailed process .